# How can I solve "We were unable to install a project on your server" in forge laravel?

Tags: laravel, server, gitlab, ssh-keys, forge

If I install repository in forge, there exist error like this :

```
Cloning into 'testshop.co.id'...
GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The full error like this :

[image]

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double-check your actual ssh URL and see if:

- GitLab recognizes you (display a "Welcome" message)

  ```
  ssh -T git@your.gitlab.server
  ```
- GitLab has you listed as the owner or member of the project you want to access (for that, you need to go to the GitLab web pages interface)

Comment: I am still confused what you say.
Can you answer in more detail?

Comment: @SuccessMan did you see a welcome message when typing `ssh -T git@your.gitlab.server` (replacing `your.gitlab.server` by your actual Gitlab server, check `git remote -v`)

Comment: Solved. I add ssh key on the source control provider(I add it use account master)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your repository link is correct? The error is that it cannot find your repository.

It should be something along the lines of UserName/ProjectName .

To ensure what it is go to whatever source control that you use and look in the URL so for my github project: 
https://github.com/KyleWardle/RomanNumerals

The link you would put in forge would be

```
KyleWardle/RomanNumerals
```

My Forge: [image: My Forge]

Comment: HTTPS has nothing to do with SSH though.

Comment: The error is nothing to do with SSH. It is talking about SSH by default as a potential problem however if you actually read the error output it is about your remote repository, not SSH.

Comment: Got it. Let's wait for the OP to tell us what this "remote" actually is...

Comment: @Kyle Wardle, Url of my project like this : `https://gitlab.com/edenhazard/footballshop.git`. I put the link in the forge like this : `edenhazard/footballshop`. It does not work

Comment: @Kyle Wardle. Solved. I add ssh key on the source control provider(I add it use account master)

Comment: Fixed by deleting repo. When installing the repo again, make sure to copy the key and go to github -> your repo -> deploy keys -> add. Not sure why this happens, really difficult so solve